# Javascript: split string into strings of specific length

Tags: javascript

I have a string to parse into Date

```
const a = '18122122'
```

and this way(constantly using substr) to parse it is ugly and error-prone

```
const date = new Date('20' + a.substr(0, 2), a.substr(2, 2) - 1, a.substr(4, 2), a.substr(6,2 ))
```

Do I miss a method like

```
const dateArray = a.<method>(2) // return ['18', '12', '21', '22']
dateArray[0] = '20' + dateArray[0]
dateArray[1] -= 1;
const date = new Date(...dateArray)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a global regular expression to match repeated instances of 2 digits, and then replace the array items as needed:

```js
const a = '18122122';
const dateArray = a.match(/\d{2}/g);
dateArray[0] = '20' + dateArray[0];
dateArray[1] -= 1;
const date = new Date(...dateArray);
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
const a = "18042019";
let [, day, month, year] = a.match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/);
new Date(year, --month, day);
```

It doesn't matter that the `Date` arguments are strings containing numbers, as the constructor will typecast each parameter to a `Number` anyway.

Comment: Yes, *and* I got the order of parameters wrong because I was reading your input back-the-front. Pro tip: when posting examples, it really, really helps to use a realistic example instead of key-mashing.